# Creating sparse matrix and then running predictive analysis on the data

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, predict, visitor-statistic

Hello R experts out here,

I am a Stata programmer trying to learn R.
I have a data framewhere each row ID has values against it as df1:

```
df1 <- data.frame(name=c("John", "Mary", "Joe", "Tim", "Bob", "Pat"),
                  v1=c(14,2,3,4,14,1),
                  v2=c(21,6,19,31,16,5),
                  v3=c(32,10,22,33,27,30),
                  v4=c(42,17,45,39,34,35),
                  v5=c(98,35,66,0,78,99),
                  v6=c(117,49,0,0, 89,186))
```

The values in the columns for each visitor ID range from 1 to 1000. These are basically the days each visitor ID visited the doctor in a period of 1000 days. Some of the patients stop visiting after offset of the symptoms and some patients continue the medication and pay routine visits as prescribed by the doctor. Some patients start visiting again after a long time if the disease relapses.

I want to create a sparse matrix of all the IDs that visited the doctor from 1 to 1000 days. Could you please suggest how to create create a sparse matrix. Its pretty simple and straight forward in Stata but I can't figure out a way in R.

The end results should be in the form:

```
name    1   2   3   4   5   6   10  14  16  17  19  21
John                                1               1
Mary        1               1   1           1       
Joe         1                               1
```

After creating the sparse matrix, I have to predict, when would be the patient's next visit to the doctor.
I was planning on creating a sparse matrix, then create a calculated variable of the difference between the last two consecutive visits and then use logistic regression on it. Could there be any more KPIs that can be generated to make a robust analysis with only the given information? Could someone please suggest if the idea is correct or if there is a better way to approach it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Multipart questions are discouraged on SO. You should edit your question to delete the las several sentences. (I suspect the "KPI" is some sort of acronym that is private to Stata users so you should define it if you post a separate question.) As far as creating a sparse matrix it's pretty easy with function in the Matrix package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question regarding how to create a sparse matrix, for which you provided a coded example can be easily answered. I don't think you need to install that package because it is in the "recommended" category of packages that get shipped with any distribution.

```
library(Matrix)
help(pac=Matrix)
M <-  Matrix(data.matrix( df1[-1]), sparse=TRUE)  # remove character column first
6 x 6 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
     v1 v2 v3 v4 v5  v6
[1,] 14 21 32 42 98 117
[2,]  2  6 10 17 35  49
[3,]  3 19 22 45 66   .
[4,]  4 31 33 39  .   .
[5,] 14 16 27 34 78  89
[6,]  1  5 30 35 99 186
```

For the revised question:

```
# first create index vectors
xix <- c( row(data.matrix(df1[-1]))[!is.na(df1[-1])])
xjy <- c(df1[-1][!is.na(df1[-1])])
```

Then supply non-NA values to index arguments and enough 1's to populate the index positions:

```
 M <- spMatrix(6, 186, i = xix, j=xjy, x=rep(1,length(c( row(data.matrix(df1[-1]))[!is.na(df1[-1])])))) 
> str(M)
Formal class 'dgTMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  ..@ i       : int [1:33] 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 1 2 3 ...
  ..@ j       : int [1:33] 13 1 2 3 13 0 20 5 18 30 ...
  ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 6 186
  ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : NULL
  ..@ x       : num [1:33] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..@ factors : list()
> M[1:6, 1:25]  # enough output to show success
6 x 25 sparse Matrix of class "dgTMatrix"

[1,] . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 . . . . . . 1 . . . .
[2,] . 1 . . . 1 . . . 1 . . . . . . 1 . . . . . . . .
[3,] . . 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 . . 1 . . .
[4,] . . . 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
[5,] . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 . 1 . . . . . . . . .
[6,] 1 . . . 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I guess I didn't ask the question right. I need to create a matrix such that all the days of visits from 1 to 1000 become the column names and it gets populated with a boolean value of 0 and 1 for each patient ID if it visited the doctor that day. Could you please help me with that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the non-visit days need to be zeros, then it is a dense matrix. The only way that you could get something that "looks" like your editted output would be a character matrix where the empty positions were encoded as `""`. I think that a sparse matrix version would be possible by using the values in your dataframe as j-arguments to one of the sparseMatrix functions. You would use the row indices as i-arguments. I think these are TsparseMatrices.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your time and quick response.